# Why does this code doesn't detect space in the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning python from zero (I've never programmed before), I was practicing "For" loop in Python 3.x trying to code a program which detects if your password is correct or not (for being correct it should have at least 8 digits and not use spaces). I've tried to code but always my program says that password is correct even if I use a space in the password, length seems to work fine.

```
contra=False

pass_=input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")

for i in pass_:
    if len(pass_)>8 and i!=" ":
            contra=True

if contra:
    print("password ok")
else:
    print("wrong password")
```

Comment: You set `contra` to true if you *find any character that is not a space*. If you want to find out if there is a space, you would set a variable when you *find a space*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is unnecessary:

```py
pass_=input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")

contra = " " not in pass_ and len(pass_)>8

if contra:
    print("password ok")
else:
    print("wrong password")
```

If you wish to keep the loop, you can rework your code:

```py
contra=False

pass_=input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")

if len(pass_)>8:
    contra = False
for i in pass_:
    if i==" ":
        contra=False

if contra:
    print("password ok")
else:
    print("wrong password")
```

There is no need to check the length of the password on every iteration.

Python supports the `in` expression, such as `a in b`, which checks if `a` exists in the iterable `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two independent conditions.  You can check for them much more simply:

```
contra = len(pass_) > 8 and \
         " " not in pass_
```

That's it: no `if` and assignment, no loop.  Simply evaluate each requirement, join them with `and`, and assign the result to `contra`.  Even more straightforward is to make that compound expression the condition of your final `if`:

```
if len(pass_) > 8 and \
         " " not in pass_:
    print("password ok")
else:
    print("invalid password")
```

Comment: thank you very much, I am learning and I don't know the syntax very well at the moment. In this particular exercise I was asked to use the "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you set the variable `contra` to True each time the character is not a space. But that means that unless all characters are spaces it will at least once be set to True.

Instead, try to look for a counterexample like this:

```py
contra = True
pass_=input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")

for i in pass_:
    if i == ' ':
        contra = False
        break

if contra and len(pass_) > 8:
    print("password ok")
else:
    print("wrong password")
```

This way as soon as a space is found you `break` out of the loop, executing no further iterations. After you can also check for the length of the password.